# How to access the dataset on API Portal (which provides REST Webservice) using SSIS

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I want to access the data sets on an API portal(using SSIS) which provides an Internet REST web service to expose certain functions to the third party applications.

I am relatively new to the Webservices concept. Could someone help me by providing a tutorial or step by step procedure on how to access the datasets on this portal using HTTPS and REST services methodology ?

Also, it has some authentication parameters that needs to be included in header of the request, like AUTH_CUSTID, AUTH_KEY and AUTH_SOURCE.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help you (depending on whether I understood your requirement):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/07/08/how-to-configure-an-ssis-package-to-access-a-web-service-using-wcf.aspx

Comment: Even before anything,  I am trying to access the source using a URL embedded with the parameters mentioned above, it doesn't work. Following is the message that gives me this kind of message  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <result>
  <status>failed</status> 
  <reason>access denied</reason> 
  </result>  What does this mean ?